# Force Exclusive Mode in VMware Workstation9?

Tags: vmware-workstation, fullscreen

Is there any way to force exclusive mode in vmware workstation 9? I hate always having to choose it in the toolbar.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/698662/how-can-i-start-a-vm-automatically-in-exclusive-mode